# how to associate an application with a new-style Facebook Page of which I'm admin?

Tags: facebook, user-accounts

I am trying to connect a new website with a Facebook page. the website is built with Wordpress CMS, and so I am using Facebook plugin Facebook Connect to allow a Facebook Like counter button on the site and maybe other functions.

The plugin states I need to get application ID.

I do not want to do this on my own personal facebook account, but rather for the clients themselves. 
I am an admin of their Facebook Page, which is done in the new style.

But it is not clear to me how to do a new app other than from my own account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the new app via https://developers.facebook.com/apps and then create a Facebook Group to administrate the new app as outlined in this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/531/)

There is currently no other way to create a Facebook app other than with a user account.

Comment: thanks! I have found an interesting post on the actual wordpress plugin which sheds more light on it. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-simple-facebook-connect-setting-up-fb-connect-with-an-organization-page?replies=6

They say that indeed you must have a user account to make an app. NO OTHER WAY. They highlight that you can assign others as admins to the app though - which might escape the issue of it being tied to a persons account.

Comment: Hmm what you said was correct, but I have now made a new question. This is because I Cannot see how to "tie" my application to the page of which I am admin?